# Problems with ParallelDo

Tags: image-processing, parallelization

As example I have the following two image sets (10 images each, png format, 8 bit gray scale) in two different directories and want to determine the mean intensity of each image:

set 1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfRS1Pb1ctcmdFNUE

set 2: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9wKP6yNcpyfZDdjRk1ya0hqUWc

The code below produces an error. 
What is the reason that the files in `dir_2` are not found?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

dirs = {"F:\\dir_1\\", "F:\\dir_2\\"};

ndir = Length[dirs];

SetSharedVariable[meanIntensity];

Do[

  SetDirectory[dirs[[j]]];

  dirBase = FileNameTake[dirs[[j]]];

  fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
  numFiles = Length[fNames];

  meanIntensity = Array[0 &, numFiles];

  ParallelDo[

   meanIntensity[[i]] = 
    ComponentMeasurements[Import[fNames[[i]], "png"], 
       "MeanIntensity"][[All, 2]][[1]];

   Print["j=", j, " i=", i, " meanIntensity=", meanIntensity[[i]]];

   , {i, 1, numFiles}

   ];

  , {j, 1, ndir}

  ];
```

The output is:

```
(kernel 2) j=1 i=5 meanIntensity=0.0228285

(kernel 4) j=1 i=1 meanIntensity=0.0225379

(kernel 3) j=1 i=3 meanIntensity=0.0227294

(kernel 1) j=1 i=6 meanIntensity=0.0227178

(kernel 4) j=1 i=2 meanIntensity=0.0225431

(kernel 3) j=1 i=4 meanIntensity=0.0224934

(kernel 2) j=1 i=7 meanIntensity=0.0223063

(kernel 1) j=1 i=8 meanIntensity=0.0227366

(kernel 4) j=1 i=9 meanIntensity=0.0227438

(kernel 3) j=1 i=10 meanIntensity=0.0225731

(kernel 4) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 3) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 2) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 1) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 4) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 3) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

During evaluation of In[4]:= ComponentMeasurements::invarg1: Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

During evaluation of In[4]:= ComponentMeasurements::invarg1: Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

During evaluation of In[4]:= ComponentMeasurements::invarg1: Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

During evaluation of In[4]:= General::stop: Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 2) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 1) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 3) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) j=2 i=1 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 3) j=2 i=3 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 2) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 1) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 4) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 3) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 2) j=2 i=5 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 1) j=2 i=6 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 4) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 3) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 2) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 1) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 4) j=2 i=2 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 3) j=2 i=4 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 2) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 1) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 4) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 3) Import::nffil :  File not found during Import.

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 3) Part::partd :  Part specification ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity][[All,2]] is longer than depth of object.

(kernel 2) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 1) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 2) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 1) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 2) j=2 i=7 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 1) j=2 i=8 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 4) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 3) ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 :  Expecting a valid label matrix, an image, or a list of an image and a label matrix instead of $Failed.

(kernel 4) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 3) General::stop :  Further output of ComponentMeasurements::invarg1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

(kernel 4) j=2 i=9 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]

(kernel 3) j=2 i=10 meanIntensity=ComponentMeasurements[$Failed,MeanIntensity]
```

**When I use `Do` instead of `ParallelDo` everything is fine:**

```
j=1 i=1 meanIntensity=0.0225379

j=1 i=2 meanIntensity=0.0225431

j=1 i=3 meanIntensity=0.0227294

j=1 i=4 meanIntensity=0.0224934

j=1 i=5 meanIntensity=0.0228285

j=1 i=6 meanIntensity=0.0227178

j=1 i=7 meanIntensity=0.0223063

j=1 i=8 meanIntensity=0.0227366

j=1 i=9 meanIntensity=0.0227438

j=1 i=10 meanIntensity=0.0225731

j=2 i=1 meanIntensity=0.0221354

j=2 i=2 meanIntensity=0.0223254

j=2 i=3 meanIntensity=0.0225109

j=2 i=4 meanIntensity=0.0220713

j=2 i=5 meanIntensity=0.0221103

j=2 i=6 meanIntensity=0.022274

j=2 i=7 meanIntensity=0.0221438

j=2 i=8 meanIntensity=0.0221835

j=2 i=9 meanIntensity=0.0223304

j=2 i=10 meanIntensity=0.0222357
```

Comment: I assume you would need to set the current directory on each subkernel as necessary.

Comment: How would that be done?

Comment: @mrz try to replace `SetDirectory[dirs[j]]` by `With[{dirj = dirs[[j]]},
 ParallelEvaluate@SetDirectory@dirj
 ]`

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: I tried your replacement but this even produces more errors: see the nb file: http://tinyurl.com/zsxxmy6 and the output: http://tinyurl.com/z4dynxg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as expected. The key issue is to use the second argument of `FileNames`.

```
dirs={"F:\\dir_1\\","F:\\dir_2\\"};
ndir=Length[dirs];
SetSharedVariable[meanIntensity];
Do[
   fNames=FileNames["*.png",{dirs[[j]]}];
   numFiles=Length[fNames];
   meanIntensity=Array[0&,numFiles];
     ParallelDo[ meanIntensity[[i]]  = ComponentMeasurements[
                 Import[fNames[[i]],"png"],             
                 "MeanIntensity"][[All,2]][[1]];
       Print["j=",j," i=",i," meanIntensity=",meanIntensity[[i]] ]
     ,
     {i,1,numFiles}
    ]   
    ,
    {j,1,ndir}   
];
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Can you explain why this small change solves the problem?

Comment: It works because you give FileNames the real full file name and all Global` symbols are distributed over the parallel kernels. Why SetDirectory on parallel subkernels does not work, I do not know. Please ask or better call Wolfram support. They will certainly know more about the mysteries of differences of subkernels from the master kernel.